# Having trouble with string to float in python

Tags: python, string, error-handling, floating-point

My goal is to create a program that will convert degrees to radians. The formula is (degrees * 3.14) / 180.  But python keeps giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2.py", line 6, in <module>
    main()
  File "2.py", line 4, in main
    degrees = (degrees * 3.14) / 180
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

From this code:

```
def main():
    degrees = raw_input("Enter your degrees: ")
    float(degrees)
    degrees = (degrees * 3.14) / 180

main()
```

EDIT: Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 8):

```
float(degrees)
```

doesn't do anything.  Or, rather, it makes a float from the string input degrees, but doesn't put it anywhere, so degrees stays a string.  That's what the TypeError is saying: you're asking it to multiply a string by the number 3.14.

```
degrees = float(degrees)
```

would do it.

Incidentally, there are already functions to convert between degrees and radians in the math module:

```
>>> from math import degrees, radians, pi
>>> radians(45)
0.7853981633974483
>>> degrees(radians(45))
45.0
>>> degrees(pi/2)
90.0
```

Comment: I would just add that Strings are immutable in python thus all operations on them create a new object, never modify the original.

Comment: Thanks!!  Yeah, I know, but my teacher wants me to make a function for that myself.

Answer (score 2):

[`float()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#float) doesn't modify its argument, it returns it as a `float`. I suspect what you want is (also adding standard `__name__` convention out of habit):

```
def main():
    degrees = raw_input("Enter your degrees: ")
    degrees = float(degrees)
    degrees = (degrees * 3.14) / 180

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What does the if __name__ == '__main__': main() do?

Comment: @netbyte check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228257/what-does-if-name-main-mean-in-python :)